# Decoding "=C3=A4" in a string

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I tried a lot of different things to get my string correctly displayed but I can't make it work.

That's the string:
`f=C3=A4hrt (German word: fährt)`

My file is encoded in utf-8, the file is loaded within Joomla.

I tried both

`$geschichte->inhalt = utf8_encode($geschichte->inhalt);`

and

`$geschichte->inhalt = mb_convert_encoding($geschichte->inhalt, "UTF-8");`
but nothing works.

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: And what happens if you just try to echo it (fährt) with no encoding? What's your initial page encoded in? Otherwise there's always `html_entity_decode('f&#228;hrt')`. One last question, what is `=C3=A4`? In what is this encoded?

Comment: If you mean with initial page my index.php: it's also utf-8.
html_entity_decode() doesn't work.
I don't know what it is and in what it encoded is - it's a mails message body from my IMAP server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This encoding has nothing to do with UTF-8 or such, it looks like [*quoted printable* encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), which is most often found in emails. Perhaps you are parsing emails and will need to heed the specific email headers and decode the content appropriately. Either way, [`quoted_printable_decode`](http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode) helps here:

```
echo quoted_printable_decode('f=C3=A4hrt');  // fährt
```

Comment: In two decades or so of staring at teh interweb you come across a lot of things…

Comment: @alve Note that QP isn't the only possible encoding you may encounter in emails, there's a whole host of things you need to be aware of and a bunch of headers you'll want to anticipate and deal with appropriately. It's best to use some existing library which will parse emails for you instead of reinventing all this yourself.

Comment: Could you kindly point out in your answer to other similar encoding problems just for reference? And maybe change the title of the question to something else to easily find this question for people with similar problems. (PS: You look 22 in your picutre, I'm surprised you said two decades.)

Comment: @deceze Do you know such a library? Even it's just a very quick "project" I'm working at I'm although interested in the libraries...

Comment: @Islam I've used that picture forever, 22 is probably a pretty accurate guess. It's my avatar and I won't change it… ;)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy That does a lot more stuff than I'd need.